# Deleting a user post in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Users should have the ability to delete notes they have created. So far I have a delete link which has auth middleware.

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('auth/notes', 'Auth\NotesController@index');
    Route::get('auth/notes/{note}/delete', 'Auth\NotesController@delete');
    Route::get('auth/notes/{note}/edit', 'Auth\NotesController@edit');
});
```

In my notes controller, I have this function which handles the deletion.

```php
public function delete($note_id)
{
    $note = Note::where('id', '=', $note_id)->first();
    $note->delete();
    flash('Your note has been deleted.');

    return redirect('/auth/notes');
}
```

However, I have noticed that any user may delete other users notes by changing the ID of the note in the delete route. I want to make a secure delete link for user's notes; any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: did you read about gates https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do here is make a post request instead of get for deletion, then utilise the `authorize()` method of the request class to check if the note actually relates to the logged-in user. Something like this:

```
if( Note::where('id', $note_id)
       ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
       ->exists();
  )
       return true;
  return false;
```